# HTML5 local storage for tile maps and feature layers using ArcGIS Java Script API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, tilecache, feature-layer, html5

I am developing a mobile arcgis application I want to store data locally so that when a user is offline he/she can use the  maps. I want to store tile layers,feature layers and a table data.

Any sample code appreciated

Platform : ArcGIS java script API and HTML5

Comment: Please check few samples @ http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/#sample/mobile_featurelayer

Answer (score 1):

As @Sunil notes: for the tiles part, see the [Tiles in local storage](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/#sample/exp_webstorage) developer sample and for the feature layers see [Local storage - experimental](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/#sample/exp_localstorage). Each sample is complete, in the sense that they're working demos, you'll still need to modify to suit your local circumstances.